# Quantum Coin Flipping Protocol

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
$I have the next protocol:

1. $A$ tosses a fair coin $a\in \{0,1\}$, if $a=0$, $A$ sends to $B$ $\ket{\psi_0}=\ket0$, if $a=1$ $A$ sends to $B$, $\ket{\psi_1}=\ket{+}$.
2. $B$ now picks randomly $b\in \{0,1\}$.
3. $A$ sends to $B$, the value of $a$.

After step 1., $B$ measures the state he gets in the basis $\{\psi_a, \psi^{\perp}_a\}$, if he doesn't get $\psi_a$ he wins, otherwise the score is $a\oplus b$, i.e if it's $0$ then $B$ wins, if it's $1$ then $A$ wins.

The question is to find the best strategy for $B$ to win if he's dishonest and $A$ is honest, and it's probability, and when B is honest and $A$ is dishonest to show that there exist a constant positive prob for which $B$ can win the game.

My attempt at solution is as follows:

For the first question:
a. Well, as far as I can see $B$ can only cheat on choosing between b=0 or 1, but still he's left with 50/50 chance of winning, I don't see better strategy.

b. Here when $A$ cheats and $B$ is honest, if $A$ picks $a = 0 \ or \ 1$, and $\psi$ he sends is different than $\phi_a$, then by the criterion of the game $B$ wins. In case $A$ doesn't cheat $B$ has 0.5 chance of winning the game.
So the probability should be (prob. A is dishonest)*(prob B to win)+(prob A is honest)*(prob B to win)= 0.5*1+0.5*0.5=0.75.

But then again, I might be wrong here. :-(

Comment: As I understood your protocols, a dishonest B can win with probability one: he just have to pretend he obtained $|\psi_a^\perp\rangle$ from his measurement. Did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: By the way, this kind of protocol is called "weak coin flipping" in the literature, and I think that protocols with arbitrary small bias are known.

Comment: I think that you are right in this regard. BTW, with question b. am I right in my analsyis?

Comment: I really don't get your analysis on several points. does "$\psi$ different of $\psi_a$" means orthogonal, or just different ? I don't understand why you need a "prob. A is dishonest" ? And why do you set it to .5. And you don't consider entanglement.

Answer (score 1):

## Cheating Bob

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
$A cheating Bob can always win. He just needs to pretend to have obtained $\ket{\psi_a^\perp}$ from his measurement.

## Cheating Alice

By definition, if Alice  cheats, she is not restricted to send one of the $\ket{\psi_a}$ states. I suspect that her optimal attack involves preparing an entangled state, sending half of it to Bob and make a measurement depending on $b$. The chosen $a$ will depend on the output value of $b$.

Let's look at a (maybe suboptimal) way for Alice to cheat.

1. Alice sends the state $\ket\phi=\frac{\ket0+\ket+}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}=\frac{(1+\sqrt2)\ket0+\ket1}{\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}}$
2. When Bob reveals $b$, Alice choses $a=b\oplus1$, to ensure $a\oplus b=1$
3. Alice sends $a$ to Bob. Let's suppose $a=0$ (the situation is obviously symmetric when $a=1$.). Bob's measurement is then $\{\ket0, \ket1\}$.

   - He gets $\ket1$ with probability $\frac1{4+2\sqrt2}=14.64\%$. Bob wins in this case.
   - He gets $\ket0$ with probability $1-\frac1{4+2\sqrt2}=85.36\%$. Since $a\otimes b=1$, Alice always wins in this case.

## A much better trivial classical protocol

As shown above, Bob's cheating probability is 100% and Alice's is at least 85\%. The following fully classical protocol is better:
  1. Alice randomly choses $a$ and tells it to Bob
  2. Bob randomly choses $b$ ant tells it to Alice.
The winner is given by $a\oplus b$. Alice cheating probability is now 50% instead of 85%, while Bob's cheating probability is no worse than in the preceding, where it was already 100% ! This protocol is therefore better than yours, even if not very useful...

## Literature on Weak Coin Flipping

The protocol you describe is called weak coin flipping. Mochon has given a protocol with arbitrary small bias in [arxiv:0711.4114](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4114) (Warning: hard to understand paper), involving several rounds of communication between Alice and Bob. An easier to understand protocol was proposed by Spekkens and Rudolph in [arXiv:quant-ph/0202118](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0202118), with a cheating probability of at most $1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: I have corrected my questions, sorry to mislead you. :-(

Comment: So you changed the order of cases to consider. I don't think it changes the validity of y answer.

Comment: But both questions ask for Bob's optimal strategy and not for Alice's!

Comment: In the usual terminology : Honest Bob = Bob follows the protocol. He doesn't have anything to optimize on, since his strategy is fixed by the protocol. And Cheating Alice = Alice can do anything. The protocol doesn't define her strategy. Finding a bound on Bob's result means therefore optimizing on Alice's strategies.

Comment: I think the BB84 protocol is the protocol that A can follow in order to maximize her chances to win the game.

Comment: I am trying to understand how can she win the game when she cheats. I mean, she can lie in the first round, i.e she gets $a$ but sends $\psi_{1-a}$ or $\psi^{\perp}_{a}$ or any combination of them that doesn't give back $\psi_a$; or she can lie in the third round and send him the value of $1-a$. But either way I don't see her optimizing her win more than 50% chance.

Comment: I've now added an explicit attack, where she has a probability 85% to win.

Comment: Well as you said I need to find the best move for Alice, well I think I need to show that no matter what Alice does, she can never win with 100%. My arguement is as follows: Alice wins whenever $a\oplus b =1$, that means that if Bob sends $b\in \{0,1\}$, Alice should send $a=1-b$ in order to win. But then if she sends in step 1 a state that is not $\phi_a$ then Bob wins, so no matter where she lies, Bob have a fair chance to win always.

Comment: I agree with your argument that Alice cannot win with 100% probability (but she can win with probability at least 85%), and Bob can win with probability 100%. However, the use of a quantum state only serves the purpose to degrading it, making the cheating more easy for Alice (85% instead of 50%) and still letting Bob cheat with probability 100%

Comment: OK, so you wrote that your strategy is suboptimal, how would I go around showing what is the optimal strategy for Alice?

Comment: My strategy is maybe suboptimal, maybe not. For example, I did not consider entanglement based strategies for Alice, and they might be better than the strategy I proposed. I just wrote the best strategy I could figure out. Since this strategy clearly shows that this protocol is worse than a simple classical protocol, I don't think it is worth investigating further.